# Use functions arrange / across on multiple column mixing asc & desc orders

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to order `iris` as following but using variable names if possible using a single statement :

```
# Result I want but using variable names
x1 <- iris %>% arrange(Species, desc(Sepal.Length))

# Working solution (with multiple statements)
x2 <- iris %>% arrange(across(any_of("Sepal.Length"), desc)) %>% arrange(across(any_of("Species")))

# My try : not working (one statement)
asc <- function(x) {return(x)}
x3 <- iris %>% arrange(across(any_of(c("Species", "Sepal.Length")), .fns = list(asc, desc)))

identical(x1, x2)
identical(x1, x3)
```

As far as I understood, when you use `arrange(across(.cols, .fns))` you can use `desc` but it will impact all of your variables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.data`:

```
x2 <- iris %>% arrange(.data[["Species"]], desc(.data[["Sepal.Length"]]))
identical(x1, x2)
## [1] TRUE
```

This can also be done in base R like this:

```
o <- order(iris[["Species"]], -xtfrm(iris[["Sepal.Length"]]))
x3 <- iris[o, ]
all.equal(x1, x3, check.attributes = FALSE)
## [1] TRUE
```

or in sql like this:

```
library(sqldf)
v1 <- "Species"
v2 <- "Sepal.Length"
x4 <- fn$sqldf("select * from iris order by [$v1], [$v2] desc")
all.equal(x1, x4, check.attributes = FALSE)
## [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is also to convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`

```
library(dplyr)
x2 <- iris %>%
       arrange(!! rlang::sym("Species"), desc(!! rlang::sym("Sepal.Length")))
identical(x1, x2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Good solution as well. To be honest the best for me would be to have a solution with the possibility to have dynamic number of variables to get something that would look like `arrange(across(.cols = c("var1", "var2", ...), .fns = list(asc, desc, ...)`